# pass wordpress template directory into ajax url call

Tags: theme-development, ajax, javascript

Can you please let me know how I can pass a template directory instead of

> http://localhost:8080/WP/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/data.php

into the URL option of an ajax call like below

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/WP/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/data.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "HTML",
    success: function() {}
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by a template directory? Keep in mind that calling files in your theme directly is a security risk and can cause a lot of problems. WP already provides the REST API for making requests, and there's the old WP Admin AJAX. You should never have to make requests directly to a theme. Additionally, look into child theming so your edits aren't deleted when twentyseventeen gets updated

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't want to hardcode your URL to `data.php`, but using a standalone file to handle requests in a theme or plugin is a major security problem.

Instead, using a REST API endpoint.

For example, lets register a `data` endpoint:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'monacoder/v1', '/data/', array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'monacoder_data'
        ) );
} );
function monacoder_data( $request ) {
    return "response";
}
```

Now we can see that if we `POST` a request to `http://localhost:8080/WP/wp-json/monacoder/v1/data/` in javascript, that it responds with the value `"response"`. The code can go in your `functions.php` or a plugin, just make sure to have permalinks turned on.

Additionally, we can enqueue the `wp-api` library:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );
```

Now you have the URL available in javascript at `wpApiSettings.root`, so you can do this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: wpApiSettings.root + "monacoder/v1/data",
    success: function() {
        // do something
    }
});
```

You can also use the `wp-api` library to fetch posts, e.g:

```
var postsCollection = new wp.api.collections.Posts();
postsCollection.fetch();
postsCollection.forEach(function( post ) {
    console.log( post );
});
```